# Unable to download research article from scihub using browser emulation with selenium

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver, cross-site

I am trying to automate the download of research articles from scihub (https://sci-hub.scihubtw.tw/) based on their corresponding article titles. I am using a library called scholarly (https://pypi.org/project/scholarly/) to get the url, author information related to the given article title as shown in the code below.

I use the fetched url (as described above) to emulate the download process using scihub. But I am unable to download directly, since I can't press the open button on the search page (https://sci-hub.scihubtw.tw/). And pressing enter after populating the query forwards me to another page with an **open button**. I am unable to fetch and press the open button for some reason and it always returns me a null element using the selenium library.

However, I am able to execute the following in the browser console and successfully download the pape,

`document.querySelector("#open-button").click()`

But, trying to get similar response from selenium is failing.

Kindly help me resolve this issue.

```
## This part of code fetches url using scholarly library from google scholar
from scholarly import scholarly
search_query = scholarly.search_pubs('Hydrogen-hydrogen pair correlation function in liquid water')
search_query = [query for query in search_query][0]


## This part of code uses selenium to automate download process
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time

download_dir = '/Users/cacsag4/Downloads'

# setup the browser
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
    "download.default_directory": download_dir, #Change default directory for downloads
    "download.prompt_for_download": False, #To auto download the file
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
    "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True #It will not show PDF directly in chrome
})

browser = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver', options=options)
browser.delete_all_cookies()

browser.get('https://sci-hub.scihubtw.tw/')

# Find the search element to send the url string to it
searchElem = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[type="textbox"]')
searchElem.send_keys(search_query.bib['url'])

# Emulate pressing enter two different ways, either by pressing return key or by executing JS
#searchElem.send_keys(Keys.ENTER) # This produces the same effect as the next line
browser.execute_script("javascript:document.forms[0].submit()")

# Wait for page to load
time.sleep(10)

# Try to press the open button using JS or by fetching the button by its ID

# This returns error since its unable to fetch open-button id
browser.execute_script('javascript:document.querySelector("#open-button").click()')

#openElem = browser.find_element(By.ID, "open-button") ## This also returns a null element
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I got the answer to this question. Sci-hub stores its pdf inside an iframe, so all you got to do is fetch the src attribute of the iframe after pressing enter on the first page. The following code does the job.

```
from scholarly import scholarly
search_query = scholarly.search_pubs('Hydrogen-hydrogen pair correlation function in liquid water')
search_query = [query for query in search_query][0]
print(search_query.bib['url'])


from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time

download_dir = '/Users/cacsag4/Downloads'

# setup the browser
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
    "download.default_directory": download_dir, #Change default directory for downloads
    "download.prompt_for_download": False, #To auto download the file
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
    "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True #It will not show PDF directly in chrome
})

browser = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver', options=options)
browser.delete_all_cookies()

browser.get('https://sci-hub.scihubtw.tw/')

# Find the search element to send the url string to it
searchElem = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[type="textbox"]')
searchElem.send_keys(search_query.bib['url'])
# Emulate pressing enter two different ways, either by pressing return key or by executing JS
#searchElem.send_keys(Keys.ENTER) # This produces the same effect as the next line
browser.execute_script("javascript:document.forms[0].submit()")

# Wait for page to load
time.sleep(2)

# Try to press the open button using JS or by fetching the button by its ID

# This returns error since its unable to fetch open-button id
#browser.execute_script('javascript:document.querySelector("#open-button").click()')

openElem = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe") ## This also returns a null element
browser.get(openElem.get_attribute('src'))
```